# Null Space and Orthogonal Complement

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonality

I'm having trouble understanding in a mathematical sense the reason why:

(1) $$Null(A) = [R(A^{T})]^\perp $$

(2) $$Null(A^T) = [R(A)]^\perp$$

What I've tried so far is picking some arbitrary vector $\vec{v}$ in $[R(A^{T})]^\perp$ . Picking some arbitrary vector $\vec{y}$ in $R(A^T)$, we then have the relation that $<\vec{v}, \vec{y}> = 0$ if (1) is true.

We can rewrite $\vec{y}$ as $A\vec{x}$ and subsitute that into the equation. This gives us:

$$<\vec{v}, A\vec{x}> = 0$$

Which can be rewritten as:

$$\vec{v}^T A\vec{x} = 0$$
$$[\vec{v}^T (A\vec{x})]^T = 0$$ since the LHS of the equation is just a 1x1 matrix.

$$ (A\vec{x})^T \vec{v} = 0$$
$$ \vec{x}^T A^T \vec{v} = 0$$

Finally, we simplify to:

$$<\vec{x}, A^T \vec{v}> = 0$$ which doesn't seem to help.

How do I show that (1) and (2) are true?

Comment: Assuming that $R$ stands for “range,” if $y\in R(A^T)$, then $y=R^Tx$, not $y=Rx$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see where I wrote $y = Rx$, did you mean where I wrote "$y$ in $R(A^T)$"?

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be $y=A^Tx$ (“We can rewrite $\vec y$ as $A\vec x$...”)

Comment: @amd Ok, I see what you mean, silly mistake by me. But I was able to figure out how to prove it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the first equality, 
$$\begin{align} 
v \in N(A) &\iff Av = 0 \\
&\iff \forall w \, \langle Av,w\rangle = 0 \tag{*}\\
&\iff \forall w \, \langle v,A^Tw \rangle = 0 \\
&\iff v \in  R(A^T)^\perp.
\end{align}$$

The only possibly tricky step is going from (*) to the preceding line, which requires the lemma that, if $\langle x,y \rangle = 0$ for all $y$, then $x=0$.

The proof for the other equality is similar.

These equalities are special cases of a broader result: If $T:V\to W$ is a linear map and $T^*: W^*\to V^*$ its adjoint, then the image of $T^*$ annihilates the kernel of $T$, and the kernel of $T^*$ annihilates the image of $T$.

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't understand your notation $ \forall w \, \langle Av,w\rangle = 0 $. Do you mean $\langle Av,w\rangle = 0 \, \forall w $?

Comment: @johnny09 No. Formally, quantifiers come before, not after the expression to which they apply.

Comment: I don’t understand why $\forall w\ \langle v,A^\mathsf Tw \rangle = 0 \iff v \in\mathrm R(A^\mathsf T)^\perp$. What is the connection there?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish Well, what’s the definition of the row space and column space of a matrix? How does this relate to the product of a matrix and a vector?

Comment: Well by definition $\mathrm R(A^\mathsf T)=\mathrm C\pmatrix{\vert & & \vert \\ a_1 & \cdots & a_n \\ \vert & & \vert} = \operatorname{Span}\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$, but we equivalently say $v\in\mathrm R(A^\mathsf T) \iff \exists x:Ax=v$. Now, $\langle v,A^\mathsf Tw \rangle = v(A^\mathsf Tw)^\mathsf T = vw^\mathsf TA=0$. I still don’t know how you arrived at your conclusion. I can see $v\perp A^\mathsf Tw$, but that’s it.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish It’s true for _all_ $w$, i.e., for all linear combinations of the columns of $A^T$. So, what is the set of all linear combinations of the columns of $A^T$?

Comment: What is confusing me is that every $A^\mathsf T w$ is in the **column** space of $A^\mathsf T$ which is the **row** space of $A$, not $\mathrm R(A^\mathsf T)$

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish Ah, I see the problem now. $R(A^T)$ here denotes “range of $A^T$,” not “row space of $A^T$,” which would be more usual. See my comment to the original question.

Comment: So *range* means “column space”?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish Indeed.