# Conjugate set of $Ax=0$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

> Let $X$ be the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\;|\;Ax=0,\;A\in\mathbb{M}_{m\times n}\}$. Find $X^{\ast}$.

It is obvious that $X^{\ast}$ is the set of all $y$ such that $y^{T}x = 0$, since if $x\in X$ the so does $-x$. But how to describe $X^{\ast}$ using matrix $A$?

Comment: This is some variation of the theorem of the four fundamental subspaces (the game of putting $^T$ and $^\perp$ anywhere it makes sense in the in an equation relating $\mathrm{im}(A)$ and $\mathrm{null}(A)$, e.g. (for this particular question) $\mathrm{null}(A)^\perp = \mathrm{im}(A^T)$).

Comment: I expect there are many questions on this topic here. This is the first one I found searching: [Null Space and Orthogonal Complement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2568876/null-space-and-orthogonal-complement)